# Local changes to file in node_modules (Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angular, module, sass, datepicker

I know that this can be a very stupid question, but I can't find matches with other posts on stackoverflow...

So: Can I modify a file of an external module , just save the file and do something that my app can listen?

At the moment, i'm trying ti change some scss style at the ng2-datepicker module (inside node_modules folder), but if I save and the launch ng serve, changes will not affect my project.

I know it's a simple problem, but i don't know the background architecture of an Angular2 project.

Thanks in advance.

(ps I've seen that i can fork the git and then do something like npm install.
Very interesting, but i also want to know how to have the same result in local)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gulp file you can tell the changed lib file path to copy to build folder check **gulp.task('copy-libs')** in code below [git repo for angular2-tour-of-heroes using gulp](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/angular2-tour-of-heroes/blob/master/gulpfile.js)

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const del = require('del');
const typescript = require('gulp-typescript');
const tscConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const tslint = require('gulp-tslint');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');
const reload = browserSync.reload;
const tsconfig = require('tsconfig-glob');

// clean the contents of the distribution directory
gulp.task('clean', function () {
  return del('dist/**/*');
});

// copy static assets - i.e. non TypeScript compiled source
gulp.task('copy:assets', ['clean'], function() {
  return gulp.src(['app/**/*', 'index.html', 'styles.css', '!app/**/*.ts'], { base : './' })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});

// copy dependencies
gulp.task('copy:libs', ['clean'], function() {
  return gulp.src([
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js',
      'node_modules/node-uuid/uuid.js',
      'node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js'
      'yourpath/changedFileName.js'
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/lib'))
});

// linting
gulp.task('tslint', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(tslint())
    .pipe(tslint.report('verbose'));
});


// TypeScript compile
gulp.task('compile', ['clean'], function () {
  return gulp
    .src(tscConfig.files)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(typescript(tscConfig.compilerOptions))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/app'));
});

// update the tsconfig files based on the glob pattern
gulp.task('tsconfig-glob', function () {
  return tsconfig({
    configPath: '.',
    indent: 2
  });
});

// Run browsersync for development
gulp.task('serve', ['build'], function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'dist'
    }
  });

  gulp.watch(['app/**/*', 'index.html', 'styles.css'], ['buildAndReload']);
});

gulp.task('build', ['tslint', 'compile', 'copy:libs', 'copy:assets']);
gulp.task('buildAndReload', ['build'], reload);
gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

Comment: I never used gulp but i'ts very interesting. Seems a little complicated for local changes but i will install it!